# how to map 'Esc' key to 'jk' in spacevim

Tags: vim, spacevim

how can I map 'esc' key to 'jk' or 'jj' in spacevim? What is the configuration file for spacevim. Is there any legendary spacevim config you can share?

Comment: You need to find some way to add `inoremap jj <Esc>` in your config. I'm not familiar with SpaceVim, but it should provide a way to add the configuration in vimscript.

Comment: You can ask in their issue tracker. Using those "vim distribution" is not recommended, since you don't know what/where they've configured and why do you need it. Sooner or later it will drive you crazy. Config your own vim, try to understand the config in your vimrc.

Comment: @jubnzv I have tried doing it in my own vimrc file but it didn't work, thanks for your help

Comment: @Kent yeah I think this is the best way of working with vim. but there is something that makes to use vimdstros are the boiler plate themes and packages that they have

Comment: I would like to mention that the file you are going to edit is going to be `~/.vimrc` file and in other forks or distros of vim or nvim you should find the proper config file or it may break your vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jubnzv mentioned, you need to find a way to add `inoremap jj <Esc>` in your config. In spacevim, you can do it with the Bootstrap functions.

> SpaceVim provides two kinds of bootstrap functions for custom configurations and key bindings, namely bootstrap_before and bootstrap_after.

First, enable the bootstrap in your config, the default path is `~/.SpaceVim.d/init.toml`

```
[options]
    bootstrap_before = 'myspacevim#before'
    bootstrap_after = 'myspacevim#after'
```

Next, create file `~/.SpaceVim.d/autoload/myspacevim.vim` with the following contents

```
function! myspacevim#before() abort
endfunction

function! myspacevim#after() abort
    inoremap jj  <Esc>
endfunction
```

More detail in the official document here: https://spacevim.org/documentation/#concepts

Comment: In the documentation I read that remapping jk to escape should be the default. https://spacevim.org/documentation/ 

Why is this not the case when I actually install it?

Comment: I found that the default behaviour to remap jk to escape could be disabled if the option `vimcompatible = true` is set. Changing it to `false` fixed the issue for me. I do not know what other side-effects it causes though.